# Difference between passing arguments to the base class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, base-class

What is the difference in passing arguments to the base class constructor?

1. `Dog::Dog(string input_name, int input_age) : Pet(input_name, input_age) { }`
2. `Dog::Dog(string input_name, int input_age) { Pet(input_name, input_age); }`

Comment: One calls the parent constructor. The other creates a temporary `Pet` object which is immediately thrown away and destructed (well at least if you add the missing semicolon, so it actually builds).

Answer (score 1):

Look the following snippet:

```
class Cat {
private:
    const int m_legs;

public:
    Cat() : m_legs{4} 
    {
    }
};
```

In the snippet above this is the only way you have to initialize a constant because `m_legs` is initialized **before** the body of constructor.

Another case is exeptions managment:

```
class Test {
private:
    ICanThrow m_throw;

public:
    Cat() try : m_throw{}
    {
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // mangage exception
    }
};
```

I usually prefer initialize member before ctor body or when I can initialize members directly in the class declaration:

```
class Cat {
public:
    void meow()
    {
    }

private:
    const int m_legs = 4;
    string m_meow{"meow"};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Pet` has no default constructor, only 1) will work.
By the time you get into the actual body of the constructor all members and bases have already been constructed. So if a base class has no default constructor you need to tell the compiler which constructor you want it initialised with, and do it before the body of the constructor - this is what the initialiser list is for.

Another reason is if a base or member is `const` - you can't modify it in the body of the constructor.